# Facebook GetUser() returns 0 without any changes of my code

Tags: facebook

I have user login implemented on my website. This was working good until now. When i try to login with Facebook account i always get 0 from GetUser(). I tryed with different web browser, updated PHP SDK to latest version, but still not working. Any clue ?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'my APP ID',
    'secret' => 'my Secret',
    'cookie' => false, // enable optional cookie support
  ));

  $user = $facebook->getUser();
  if ($user) {
    try {
      // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/ID HIDDEN");
      if (!isset($_SESSION['prijavljen'])) { 
        $_SESSION['prijavljen'] = True;
      }
      if (!empty($likes['data'])) $fblike = true; else $fblike = false;    
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
      $user = null;
    } 
  }
  // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
  if ($user) {
    //$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => 'my URL'));
    } else {
    $params = array('scope' => 'email,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_hometown,user_likes', 'redirect_uri' => curPageURL());
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);  
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked [Google](https://www.google.com/search?%7Bgoogle:acceptedSuggestion%7Doq=facebook+getuser+returns+0&%7Bgoogle:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter%7Dsourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=facebook+getuser+returns+0&hl=en) for this very common question?

Comment: Yes I checked Google, but none of resolutions described works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was the PHP version on your server recently updated? You can try [this fix](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/) and see if `getUser()` function starts working for you again.

Comment: I changed PHP version from PHP 4 to PHP 3 and it looks that it's working now.